# Iterating through tabs to search for string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a function for a Chrome extension, and I need some help debugging.

The function should get a user's String input from a popup.html text box, and look through all the tabs in the current window to see if the String input is present in any of the tabs. Finally, I give an alert telling the user which tab(s) (indices: 0, 1, ...) the string was found in.

background.js

```
//searches all tabs for the input string
function searchEverywhere(searchString) {
    var indices = [];
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
        var numOfTabs = tabs.length;
        for(i = 0; i < numOfTabs; i++) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, updateProperties, function(tab) {
                if(getText().indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
                    indices.push(i);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
    return indices;
}
function makeAlert(pagesFound) {
    alert("Your input was found on tabs: " + pagesFound.toString());
}
function getText() {
    return document.body.innerText;
}
```

popup_script.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    document.querySelector('#btnSearch').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var searchString = document.querySelector('#textToSearch');
        var pagesFound = backgroundPage.searchEverywhere(String(searchString.value));
        backgroundPage.makeAlert(pagesFound);
    });
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Work with tabs</title>
        <script src="popup_script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><div class="searchEverywhere">
        Search all tabs for word:<br>
            <input type="text" name="textToSearch" id="textToSearch">
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `getText()` function always gets the text of the background page. It needs to get text of each tab.

Comment: How can I get the text of each tab?

Comment: I've added a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) we can retrieve the `innerText` of the tab.

**background.js**

```
function searchEverywhere(searchPhrase, callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        //query only tabs that you have enabled permissions for or you will get errors in console
    }, tabs => {
        let foundInTabIds = [];

        for (let tab of tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                code: `document.body.innerText`
            }, (results => {
                if (results && results.length > 0) {
                    let tabText = results[0];
                    if(tabText.indexOf(searchPhrase) > -1) {
                        foundInTabIds.push(tab.id);
                    }
                }
            }));
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            //your alert
            callback(foundInTabIds);
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

**popup.js**

```
...

var pagesFound = backgroundPage
    .searchEverywhere(String(searchString.value), backgroundPage.makeAlert);

...
```

For simplicity, I use `setTimeout`, but that's not an optimal way to wait for all callbacks to complete. I suggest using promises.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but this code doesn't work and also broke the other functions in my extension ><

Comment: `document.body.innerText` returns a string: therefore, `let tabText = results[0]` takes just the first character. Remove that line and substitute `tabText.indexOf ...` for `results.indexOf ...`

Comment: I edited it to be able to fit in your code.
@IvánNokonoko, nope.